# Why is it unnecessary to initialize SwiftUI View multiple times when using @EnvironmentObject inside?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have this sample code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    init() {
        print("Init ContentView")
    }
    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            NavigationView {
                ExampleView()
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ExampleView: View {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    init() {
        print("Init ExampleView")
    }
    var body: some View {
        ChildView()
    }
}

struct ChildView: View {
    init() {
        print("Init ChildView")
    }
    var body: some View {
        Text("Child Text")
    }
}
```

When I run it, I see these lines printed out:

```
Init ContentView
Init ExampleView
Init ChildView
Init ChildView
Init ChildView
```

It only happens when I have `@Environment(.presentationMode) var presentationMode` in my `ExampleView`. This is just a demo code, in a real project, initializing the child Views unnecessarily can cause significant lag in the application.

Has anyone encountered this issue and found a solution? Or is this a bug in SwiftUI? I tried with `Equatable`, but it didn't work.

Comment: " initializing the child Views unnecessarily can cause significant lag in the application" -- It shouldn't. Initializing structs should be extremely lightweight. Are you doing something inside `init`?

Comment: The code doesn't reproduce the issue for me: only calls `Init ChildView` once. And generally `@Environment(\.presentationMode)` is only true when view is _presented_ (not just _shown_). For example using a `sheet`. So I don't think it will even be true in this case...

Comment: SwiftUI inits View structs for all kinds of reasons, e.g. state invalidation. I wouldn't worry about it. If you have a lag it might be a memory leak e.g. initing objects somewhere instead of only using structs.

Comment: When I changed it to ```@Environment(.isPresented) private var isPresented```, the structs no longer initialized multiple times, and ```presentationMode``` is deprecated. My application is lagging because I am initializing many objects inside the ChildView. If that's really the problem, I'll look for ways to improve it.